# Is it possible to generate dynamic claims based on attributes using WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ldap, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 and several LDAP user stores.
I need to integrate AWS as a service provider and WSO2 IS as identity provider.

The situation is: I have lots of users stored in the user stores and some of them have specific roles that should be allowed to login to AWS service.  So far I don't have the possibility to alter / update the current user stores.

That's why I'm trying to figure out a way to populate / generate / translate / calculate the value of a claim based on an already stored attribute in the user store.

I have a sort of table with the groups coming from LDAP's memberOf attribute a user could belong to and their equivalences to AWS attributes that should be stored in specific claims in order for AWS to allow that user to enter certain services.

The end user is willing to solve this situation within the WSO2 IS component without altering the stores content.

I'm wondering if the only way to do this is writing a custom User Store Manager or a Custom Claim Handler [1] to deal with this particular situation or there is a more standard way to accomplish this.

I will appreciate any input, thanks in advance

[1] http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.ca/2014/07/adding-custom-claims-to-saml-response.html

Comment: Most probably your use case can be done with [claim mapping](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Claim+Management), without writing any custom components.

Comment: Well, it would be great if I could do some sort of claim mapping but so far as I know I have to chose an attribute from my User Store to do the mapping.  In my use-case the value for the claim is not in the User Store, that is why I have to calculate the value for the claim based on an attribute already stored in the User Store.

Comment: So your requirement is to calculate a claim value dynamically based on existing claim values. And would it be sufficient if this transformation happens just before send back a response like SAML or OIDC etc?

Comment: Yes, you are right Farasath.  To complement, let me tell you I'm returning a SAML response with a set of assertions. Some of those assertions are the ones that should be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Claim Handler is the right place to implement your logic. You can find a sample in https://github.com/mefarazath/CustomClaimHandler

Comment: Thanks Farasath, I will give it a try.  I agree that Custom Claim Handler should be the right place to implement it.